# Routing error after changing of language

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a asp.net core 1.1 mvc application where I get a routing error (404) after changing language. It works fine in testing mode (localhost) - but not in production - IIS.

This is my url before I click the language change button.

http://subdomain.myurl.com/SiteName/Controller/Action/Id

My View code look like this:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocOptions

@{
    var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.DisplayName })
        .ToList();
}

<div title="@Localizer["Request culture provider:"] @requestCulture?.Provider?.GetType().Name">
    <form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="ChangeLanguage"
          asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path"
          method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        @Localizer["Language"] <select name="culture"
                                        onchange="this.form.submit();"
                                        asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems"></select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then my controllercode look like this:

```
   public class ChangeLanguageController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture,                                          string returnUrl)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
                new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
            );
            ViewBag.Er = returnUrl;
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
    }
```

After the:
return LocalRedirect(returnUrl)
my Url look like this - and I get an error:

http://subdomain.myurl.com/Controller/Action/Id

My MapRoute look like this:

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

Any ide what is wrong?
Thanks!